# How to create PipelineJob with pipeline spec stored in GCS

Tags: rest, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

Trying to create a PipelineJob following the [Vertex AI API](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.pipelineJobs/create) docs.

According to the docs, if a templateUri is given then it will use it to download the pipelineSpec

> A template uri from where the PipelineJob.pipeline_spec, if empty, will be downloaded.

But when calling the API, it is complaining about missing required field.

## REQUEST

```
{
    "displayName": "pipeline test",
    "templateUri": "gs://bucket-name/3a279d63-f965-4db2-b54c-ad933b04d278.json"
}
```

`POST -` [`POST https://{service-endpoint}/v1/{parent}/pipelineJobs`](https://aiplatform/v1/.../pipelineJobs)

---

## RESPONSE

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Required field pipelineInfo is not specified. ",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

## EXPECTED

PipelineInfo downloaded from templateUri

Answer (score 0):

The closest I got to resolving this issue was when I found that the pipelineInfo has a field called "name" from google.
[image]

After I provide some random name, it throws the following error. I couldn't find reference for the "tasks" field either from the documentation.

```
"error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Required field tasks is not specified. ",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"}
```

Comment: Alternatively, there's a way to trigger the pipeline using a cloud function-pubsub trigger. Here's some reference: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/trigger-pubsub